# Context Menu visible for specific files

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I add a custom context menu item to a texteditor with

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
     <menu label="Sample Menu">
        <command commandId="HelloPlugin2.commands.sampleCommand"/> 
     </menu>        
 </menuContribution>
```

Is it possible to enable this entry only when a .java file is opened?
My naive attempt was

```
<visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
           <with variable="extension">
              <equals value="java"/>
           </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

but clearly this does not work...

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```xml
<visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
         <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.contentTypeId"
            value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource"/>
    </adapt>
</visibleWhen>
```

This requires the object to be adaptable to a file and that the file content type is Java Source.